# How to I prevent the <?xml> tag after an XSL transformation in Apigee X

Tags: xml, xslt, apigee

I'm experiencing an issue while using Json2XML and XSL transformation in Apigee X and looking for any suggestions. Here is the scenario.

The user sends a Payload in JSON format which has array of objects which I have to convert into an XML using multiple policies and send to SOAP webservice. Here is what I implemented in the Flow condition policy

1. Used a JSONtoXML transformation
2. Next I used an XSL transformation to convert the XML result into the format that SOAP service expects.

Both the policies work but I observe that the root XML element is added for JSON transformation. How do I remove the root  tag after the transformation? My SOAP service isn't welcoming the  tag in the SOAP body. Any help is appreciated. I will attach the policies to this question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

JSON Payload from user:

```
{
   "putPlcExamScore": {
      "Student": [
         {
            "ID": "Professor",
            "Form": "S",
            "GradePoints": "123"
         },
         {
            "ID": "Snape",
            "Form": "7",
            "GradePoints": "322"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

JSONtoXML Policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<JSONToXML continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="JX-JsontoXML">
    <DisplayName>JX-JsontoXML</DisplayName>
    <Properties/>
    <Options>
        <NullValue>NULL</NullValue>
        <NamespaceBlockName>#namespaces</NamespaceBlockName>
        <DefaultNamespaceNodeName>$default</DefaultNamespaceNodeName>
        <NamespaceSeparator>:</NamespaceSeparator>
        <TextNodeName>#text</TextNodeName>
        <AttributeBlockName>#attrs</AttributeBlockName>
        <AttributePrefix>@</AttributePrefix>
        <InvalidCharsReplacement>_</InvalidCharsReplacement>
        <ObjectRootElementName>Root</ObjectRootElementName>
        <ArrayRootElementName>Array</ArrayRootElementName>
        <ArrayItemElementName>Item</ArrayItemElementName>
    </Options>
    <OutputVariable>request</OutputVariable>
    <Source>request</Source>
</JSONToXML>
```

XSLT Transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XSL continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="XSLT-ConvertPayload">
    <DisplayName>XSLT-ConvertPayload</DisplayName>
    <Properties/>
    <Source>request</Source>
    <ResourceURL>xsl://PlacementScores.xsl</ResourceURL>
    <Parameters ignoreUnresolvedVariables="true"/>
    <OutputVariable>ps_modifiedpayload</OutputVariable>
</XSL>
```

XSL Resource:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <put:putPlcExamScore xmlns:put="http://something.v1">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//Student" group-by="ID">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <put:Student>
                    <put:ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                    </put:ID>
                    <put:Form>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Form"/>
                    </put:Form>
                    <put:GradePoints>
                        <xsl:value-of select="GradePoints"/>
                    </put:GradePoints>
                </put:Student>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </put:putPlcExamScore>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Part of AssignMessage policy:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    {ps_modifiedpayload}
</soapenv:Body>
```

Here is what I see in the trace

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <put:putPlcExamScore xmlns:put="something.v1">
    <put:Student>
      <put:ID>Professor</put:ID>
      <put:Form>S</put:Form>
      <put:GradePoints>123</put:GradePoints>
    </put:Student>
    <put:Student>
      <put:ID>Snape</put:ID>
      <put:Form>7</put:Form>
      <put:GradePoints>322</put:GradePoints>
    </put:Student>
  </put:putPlcExamScore>

</soapenv:Body>
```

If you observe there is the root XML tag there.`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` How do I avoid that tag in there? Hope I gave all the info required.

Thanks
Kranthi

Comment: Does an explicit `<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>` help?

Comment: Hello Martin, 

Thanks for the wonderful suggestion. It works like a charm. You saved me several hours of custom javascript coding. Appreciate your time in responding back. Have a great day.

Thanks
Kranthi